# Shadow background and make it unclickeble when pop-up occurs

Tags: javascript, dom

When a button is clicked i create a DIV and make it like a pop-up window, but i want the background around this box to be 'shadowed' and that it's not possible to click on the links and inputfields there.

How can you make this with javascript?

Comment: it is called MODAL and it is easier to do with a js framework like jQuery. As easy as this: `$('#basicModalContent').modal();`[demos](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/)

Comment: check this link for modal popup:    http://www.modalpopups.com/demos/0.2/demo.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly inside the `<body>` create a `<div>` and give it an `id`. In your `<style>` tag, give it the following style attributes (you can add more if you want):

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 3;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0.5);
```

Raise its z-index as you see fit (make sure the pop-up has a higher z-index, though). You can also adjust the opacity of its color by changing the 4th value of the `rgba()` object, ranging from 1 (opaque) to 0 (transparent). If it doesn't occupy the entire page, make sure the `<body>` and `<html>` tags don't have style attributes giving them `margin`s, `padding`, or `border`s.